# Adding a tomcat server to Intellij 13 Ultimate producer error

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a tomcat server to Intellij under Edit Run Configurations -> Add -> Tomcat Server -> Local. On selecting the tomcat server directory, I'm seeing an error message that reads `Error: Duplicate context path '/'`.

I'm new to developing apps in tomcat, and I have no idea what this error means. Googling for this turns up exact two results, both of which are unhelpful.

Could the community help me understand what this error means, and how to fix it/get around it?

PS: I'm using Intellij 13 Ultimate, Tomcat 6 (don't ask why), Mac OSX 10.10 and JRE 1.7

Answer (score 5):

I am using version 12.1.4 and have seen a similar error when I have duplicate wars marked for deployment under the deployment tab. Be sure to check you are not deploying your wars twice under the same port

### [IntelliJ Deployment Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNNAm.jpg)

Hope this helps. Here is a link to the Tomcat, IntelliJ docs:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html

Comment: Updated link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html